# Como dimiuir o tamanho de uma imagem Blob?

Tags: android

Tenho uma imagem em Blob no banco, ela está em alta resolução, eu precisava diminuir a resolução dela. Alguém sabe como  fazer isso? Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O fato de estar em blob nao tem relação com o problema. Você tem que ler do blob, fazer a operação necessária e salvar no blob de novo. Se fosse um arquivo seria a mesma coisa.

Comment: Quer diminuí-la para que efeito?

Comment: Estou tenho o erro de OutofMemoryError porque minha imagem é muito grande. Em uma tela que apresento várias imagens de tamanho pequeno, eu queria diminuí-las já que não vou precisar delas grandes na tela que está dando erro?

Comment: Vai precisar delas "grandes" em algum outro lugar?

Comment: sim, quando eu clicar em uma imagem pequena tenho que apresentar ela "grande".

Comment: em **php** eu faço isso com o **gd** http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.imagecopyresized.php

Comment: Eu estava pegando o Blob e "setando" dentro de um BitMap, mas consegui resolver o problema usando o BitMapFactory options e utilizando o método "inSampleSize", funcionou como eu precisava. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: hum... mas desse jeito o blog é enviado "grande" para o cliente e depois feito o resize, isso não deixa o site lento ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode diminuir as dimensões de uma imagem usando o [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) passado ao [BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options%29).

Escreva um método auxiliar para calcular o valor de [BitmapFactory.Options.inSampleSize](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inSampleSize):

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // Altura e largura da imagem original
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

         //Calcula o maior valor "inSampleSize" que é uma potência de 2 e mantém tanto
         // a altura e largura maior do que a altura e largura solicitada
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Escreva um método que retorne um *Bitmap* com o tamanho pretendido:

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromByteArray(byte[] byteArray,
                                                      int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    //Primeiro descodifica com inJustDecodeBounds = true para obter as dimensões originais
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.lenght, options);

    // Calcula o valor inSampleSize a usar para obter as dimensões pretendidas.
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

    // descodifica a imagem com as dimensões pretendidas.
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(byteArray, 0, byteArray.lenght, options);
}
```

Use assim:

```
Bitmap imagem = decodeSampledBitmapFromByteArray(byteArray, reqWidth, reqHeight);
```

<sub>Adaptado da [documentação](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap).</sub>

**Princípios que sigo quando uso BD e imagens:**

- As imagens "grandes" são sempre guardadas num ficheiro no cartão SD.
- Quando apenas necessito da imagem "grande", guardo no BD o *path* ao seu ficheiro.
- Quando necessito de aceder frequentemente(px. ListView) a uma imagem reduzida, guardo-a no BD.
- Quando necessito da imagem "grande" e da reduzida, guardo o *path* à imagem "grande" e a imagem reduzida no BD.
- A imagem "grande" é sempre obtida/lida assincronamente.