# No android qual a classe correspondende a classe Image do javaFX

Tags: android, java-ee, javafx

Tenho servidor de imagens implementado em javaEE, no javaFX faço uma requisição da imagem ao servidor que me retorna um array de bytes, com este resultado crio a imagem no lado cliente:

** Imagem no formato PNG.

```
byte buffer[] -> image bytes retornado pelo servidor

// no javaFX    
Image image = new Image(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
```

Como faço para criar a imagem a partir do array de bytes no android?

No servidor leio a imagem da seguinte forma:

```
private byte[] readImage(String imageName) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File fle = new File(imageName); 
    FileInputStream new FileInputStream(fle);   

    byte buf[] = new byte[(int) fle.length()];

    rea.read(buf,0,buf.length);         

    rea.close();

    return buf;                                 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A classe usada no Android para trabalhar com imagens cujo formato representa um mapa de *bits* é [Bitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html).

Tendo o *array* de *bytes* use o método [decodeByteArray()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeByteArray(byte[],%20int,%20int)) da classe [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) para descodificar o *array* em um *Bitmap*.

Use assim:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.lenght);
```

É possível redimensionar a imagem ao mesmo tempo que se descodifica passando um objecto [BitmapFactory.Options](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html) ao método `decodeByteArray()`, veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116169/2541) como.

Comment: Testei e o BitmapFactory retorna null. Imagino que o erro não esteja no byte array retornado pelo servidor porque no javaFX a imagem é criada corretamente. Será que tem mais algum segredo?

Comment: Que eu saiba não há mais segredo algum. Como é que você está a codificar o byte array?

Comment: Editei a pergunta e adicionei o método de leitura no servidor.

Comment: Não sei qual será o problema. Só posso dizer que se o *byte array* é uma representação válida de um JPEG ou PNG o método `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray()` fará a descodificação para um *Bitmap*.

Comment: O problema estava no PNG. Salvei a imagem como JPG e o decode funcionou. Editei o PNG e salvei o decode funcionou. **** A imagem que eu estava usando como teste eu baixei de https://design.google.com/icons/.